# How do I run a test to check if Google Chrome is running (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome

I've been working on a script to automate some things in chrome, and i've gotten stuck on the simplest task. How do I run a test to check if Chrome is currently running on my pc? I was previously using pywinautos find_windows, but that only checks the tab name.

something like:

```
def chrome_running():
        if 'google-chrome' running:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm willing to use any modules. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you try to check running processes or running services to determine whether chrome is running or not??

Comment: You can try this: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Selenium-how-to-detect-if-browser-is-close. This answers when the `browser is close`, but what you can do it, `get a bool`, check `if the chrome is closed or not`, `if not`, that means `chrome is open`

Comment: @Abhijeetk431, That's a little vague. I personally know when it's running or not. i'm trying to get the program to know. If it's not, the program reopens Chrome. If it is, then it does nothing. If you're referring to python checking tasklist, then no I haven't. I don't know how to do that. I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try psutil module as following:-

```
import psutil

def if_process_is_running_by_exename(exename='chrome.exe'):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        # This will check if there exists any process running with executable name
        if proc.info['name'] == exename:
            return True
    return False
```

This is checked on Window machine. You can play around with the executable name to make it work on other OSs also. Reference:- https://pypi.org/project/psutil/